# ASP.NET MVC 4 Security schema with my own database tables and columns

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, entity-framework-5, webmatrix

i'm total newbie about security with MVC4. I develop an MVC APP using WebMatrix. Its pretty cool but i didnt like the tables and columns schema.
I'm using REVERSE ENGINE CODE FIRST and i want to know what is the right thing to do. I'm reading a lot about membership providers and webmatrix.
There is a way wich i can use WebSecurity class with my own database? My login method isnt the simple login pattern (string user|username|email, string password). This application requires a long as login user like long userKEY, string password.

I'm totally confused about the terms and any kind of hint can help a lot.

Thanks

Comment: I would say do *not* create your own login implementation. Way to easy to make a mistake. Instead, figure out how to customize the built-in security to do what you want. The built-in functionality has been tested and is secure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WebSecurity` class is a wrapper around the `SimpleMembershipProvider` which is designed to work with SQL Server and SQL Compact 4.0. The schema that it works with is hard-coded into the `SimpleMembershipProvider` so you cannot use the WebSecurity class for your own schema.

However, you can [build your own provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) based off `ExtendedMembershipProvider` and have it communicate with any backing store you like. Probably the easiest/quickest thing to do is go to the [source code for SimpleMembershipProvider](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs) and copy that, altering the SQL in the various methods as required.

Comment: Totally what I was looking for :)
Its help me a lot. Thanks Mike!

Comment: Do you know what is this PreviousProvider?